# How to reverse urls in Wagtail?

Tags: django, url, wagtail

I have a Django site which contains a blog. To get it up and running quickly I just added some static blog posts using Django's TemplateView.

I have now added Wagtail and set up a blog platform using that.

The problem I now have is linking to blog posts from elsewhere in the site. Is there a way to reverse the urls for teh blog posts created in Wagtail (using the slug)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See either

- [pageurl](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/writing_templates.html?#pageurl) to reverse a URL given a Page object `{% pageurl page_object %}`, or
- [slugurl](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/writing_templates.html?#slugurl) to reverse a URL given a Page object's slug `{% slugurl some_slug %}`

If you have a Page object, you can also use `{{ page_object.url }}`, but that doesn't give you the nice multiple-site behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to reverse wagtail **admin** urls and create menu link on wagtail admin page to make creation of blogs more comfortable

```
from wagtail.admin.menu import MenuItem
from wagtail.core import hooks # for wagtail v 2.15
# from wagtail import hooks # for wagtail v3

from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.admin.utils import quote


@hooks.register('register_admin_menu_item')
def register_news_menu_item():
    page = BlogIndexPage.objects.first()
    blogs_url = reverse('wagtailadmin_explore', args=(quote(page.pk),))
    return MenuItem('Blogs', blogs_url, icon_name='doc-empty-inverse', order=1)
```